# After upgrading to macOS Monterey my Vagrant environment will not launch due to VirtualBox

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox, macos-monterey

I am relatively new to coding having completed a bootcamp. After upgrading my MacBook Air to macOS Monterey my Vagrant environment gives me the following error related to VirtualBox after typing `vagrant up`.

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant for controlling VirtualBox. 
The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "21964235-7d9e-409f-b4f5-873337ff15cb", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error:   
The virtual machine 'coding-environment_default_1569969188652_73979' has terminated unexpectedly during startup because of signal 10  
VBoxManage: error:   
Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

Is this because VirtualBox is not yet compatible with macOS Monterey?  I'm running the latest version of VirtualBox. If not, is there a workaround?

Comment: From my experience, you can hope for a compatible version of VirtualBox in half a year or so. If you own an M1-based mac you will definitely **never** get a compatible version; the reason is that VirtualBox (as most other viertualizers) doesn't actually emulate any architecture; instead it "only" works based on hypervisors that are based on the architecture the VM Engine is designed for.

Comment: Ugghh.  And I have an M1-based mac on order to replace this via trade in.  Is there another coding environment I can install and use instead and still access my projects?

Comment: Maybe Parallels can help, I'm not sure if it can import Virtual Boxes. Aside from that, don't trade-in, you may find a solution where your VM is running on your "old" machine and you only access it from your new Mac. Why do you need a VM as a "coding environment"?

Comment: That's the only coding environment I was taught to use in Bootcamp.  Other suggestions are welcome.  I'm just new to all of this.

Comment: What does this coding environment comprise of? If it's based on servers running in vagrant containers, you won't run that on an M1, but you can run that on any machine that supports X86 architecture and access any server it contains via your local network.

Comment: It is based on servers running in vagrant containers unfortunately.

Comment: Your current Mac can't be that old if you were able to upgrade to Monterey. Why are you trying to replace it?

Comment: Because the 13" screen is too hard on my eyes even with my glasses.  That's really the only reason.  It's only 2 years old.

Comment: Just get an external display then, and for the time being either downgrade to Big Sur (e.g. from any Time Machine backup), or make your machine a dual boot system and go for Fedora 35 (which btw is beautiful and amazing!).

Comment: Gotcha.  I appreciate your input.  Really disappointing about the M1-based Mac but that matches what was suggested when I was researching this.  Thanks

Comment: Temporary workaround https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/12557#issuecomment-955152390